# Data which would give me same eigenvectors?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

Any suggestion on what kind of dataset lets say nXd (n rows, d columns) would give me same eigenvectors?.

I believe it should be the one with like same absolute values in each cell. Like alternating +1 and -1. But it seems to work otherwise.

Any pointers?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~greenfie/vnx/math250/quiz8examples.html) website for some sample 2x2 and 3x3 matrices and their corresponding eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit open ended, but there are many ways with the basic idea being **start with the eigenvectors you want and alter the eigenvalues and/or re-arrange the eigenvectors to create different data sets**.

Here's two simple working examples.  First, you can just scale the eigenvalues of matrix A and then generate matrix B which will be different but has the exact same eigenvectors (in the same order):

```
>>> import numpy
>>>
>>> numpy.random.seed(1)
>>> A = numpy.random.random((2, 2,))
>>> A = numpy.matrix(A)
>>>
>>> E, Q = numpy.linalg.eig(A)
>>>
>>> B = (Q * numpy.diag(2 * E) * Q.I)
>>>
>>> print(A)
[[  4.17022005e-01   7.20324493e-01]
 [  1.14374817e-04   3.02332573e-01]]
>>> print(B)
[[  8.34044009e-01   1.44064899e+00]
 [  2.28749635e-04   6.04665145e-01]]
>>>
>>> EP, QP = numpy.linalg.eig(A)
>>> print(Q)
[[  9.99999509e-01  -9.87408230e-01]
 [  9.91087124e-04   1.58192878e-01]]
>>> print(QP)
[[  9.99999509e-01  -9.87408230e-01]
 [  9.91087124e-04   1.58192878e-01]]
```

You could generate an infinite number of unequal matrices with the same eigenvectors using this method.   In fact, the eigenvalues can be a random diagonal matrix if you want.

Another method (among many) is to rearrange the eigenvectors and eigenvalues:

```
>>> QF = numpy.fliplr(Q)
>>> C = (QF * numpy.diag(-1.0 * E) * QF.I)
>>> print(A)
[[  4.17022005e-01   7.20324493e-01]
 [  1.14374817e-04   3.02332573e-01]]
>>> print(C)
[[ -3.02332573e-01   7.20324493e-01]
 [  1.14374817e-04  -4.17022005e-01]]
>>> EF, QF = numpy.linalg.eig(C)
>>> print(Q)
[[  9.99999509e-01  -9.87408230e-01]
 [  9.91087124e-04   1.58192878e-01]]
>>> print(QF)
[[  9.99999509e-01  -9.87408230e-01]
 [  9.91087124e-04   1.58192878e-01]]
```